# Very Slow Wordpress Performance after moving to VPS?

Tags: wordpress, performance, google-pagespeed

We are struggling with the speed on our wordpress website. Have just moved to a VPS and this hasn't helped the speed at all.

Can anyone offer any recommendations on what needs to be done?

link to the website >> [salon99.co.uk](http://salon99.co.uk)

Comment: Contact the host provider.  Often when moving a site, there's optimizations that the host provider can make to help significantly.

Answer (score 0):

You have some javascript errors, looks like not loading properly. How much ram your vps have, thats other issue might be. Avoid 404 on resources (images, css, js)

Check some tips from here

http://tecadmin.net/security-tips-for-lamp-stack-on-linux/
https://askubuntu.com/questions/60298/how-do-i-properly-set-up-and-secure-a-production-lamp-server
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/building-for-production-web-applications-deploying

Provide more information on your setup.

Try install Google PageSpeed and test your site here

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsalon99.co.uk%2F&tab=mobile

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. 4gb of RAM, 120gb disk space? Does this seem sufficient?

Comment: do you have lamp stack or something else

Comment: I'm unsure what lamp stack is. But I think so

Comment: I have updated answer also consider 8gb ram and SSD.

Comment: Did you managed to make it quick. Did my answer helped? If please accept it.

Comment: Hi, sorry I haven't been back on. Unfortunately not. We have been having a bit of a nightmare moving hosts. That has been done. All the same errors remain! We got up to A/B on GTMetrix but the site was still running horrendously. Also, Keep Alive wont enable! Have done this through the Apache Config and the htaccess. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Running your site through Pingdom shows a 4 second *time to first byte.* This suggests you main issue is definitely server side. There's a couple of diagnosis plugins that you can install which will reveal which plugins may be slowing things down*, and which DB queries are expensive:

1. [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/)
2. [Debug Bar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/)
3. [P3](https://wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/)

Once you've worked out where the slow downs are coming from, you'll be in a better position to solve them. You might find you have one query in particular that is especially slow.

* I've always found WooCommerce to be on the sluggish side, but *them's the breaks.*

Comment: Ahh, I contacted our VPS host and they said the issue lies in the php! This is nothing short of a nightmare. We were advised that the issue is the php, javascript and CSS. I dont know how to fix this!

Comment: @JSALON99 Your host is likely right; it's going to be a server-side issue (i.e . PHP & DB queries). Start by installing one of the plugins above: they will point you towards which queries in particular are slow, so note them down. Repeat with the other plugins. Once you've narrowed it down, you'll be able to ask more specific questions. Without further information it's like going to the doctor and saying "I'm sick, help me"  but not providing any further symptoms.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Its very helpful. I have downloaded the Query Monitor. I'm getting 1 slow query and 1 duplicate query. Are these likely to cause such a slow delay? I'm unsure of what I'm looking for. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @JSALON99 It's been a while since I've used it, but I'm pretty sure you can click on the slow query and it will tell you how long it takes, and which function is making the query, which is the first step in working out where the problem is. It might be on query that is exceptionally slow, or several queries that add up.